# InlineKeyboard + Webhook

Tags: go, telegram, webhooks, telegram-bot

I develop a telegram bot and use webhook. Nevertheless, I don't know how to use InlineKeyboard and CallbackQuery. If anyone know, pls write a simple example lower

My try:

```
func AddFundsAction(botText BotMessage, NewBot *tgBotApi.BotAPI) {
    chatUser := int64(botText.Message.From.Id)
    markup := tgBotApi.NewInlineKeyboardMarkup(
        tgBotApi.NewInlineKeyboardRow(
            tgBotApi.NewInlineKeyboardButtonData("3", "3"),
        ),
    )
    reply := tgBotApi.NewMessage(chatUser, "hello, world!")
    reply.ReplyMarkup = &markup
    res, _ := NewBot.Send(reply)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Error:

```
Bad Request: chat not found
```

Comment: The chat is not found because you probably supply the wrong ID to `tgBotApi.NewMessage`. `chatUser` should probably be set to `botText.Message.Chat.ID`. As in the user id is not the same as the id of the chat with that user

Comment: @xarantolus it isn't working anyway

Comment: Is it the same error message? Did you change your code to show the error returned from `NewBot.Send` that you're ignoring in the question? Also maybe look into [this issue](https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/issues/196).

Comment: @xarantolus Yes, the same problem. I only see examples with updates, but I use a webhook and I don't know how to get an answer, that button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

I used a HandlFunc instead of a ListenWebHook and I couldn't realise my idea.
It works for me:

```
setWebhook(NewBot)
    updates := NewBot.ListenForWebhook("/" + configuration.BOT_TOKEN)
    go successfulPaymentListen()
    go http.ListenAndServeTLS(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", configuration.BOT_HOST, configuration.BOT_PORT), configuration.CERT_FILE, configuration.CERT_KEY, nil)
    for update := range updates {
        if update.Message != nil {
            recognizeCommand(update)
        } else if update.CallbackQuery != nil {
            log.Print(update.CallbackQuery.Data)
        }
    }
```